# How to understand expressions as method parameters in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am starting to see methods like the one below used more and more, but it's a concept that I don't fully understand.

```
    public virtual Task<List<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)
    {
        using (var conn = _factory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            return conn.SelectAsync(exp);
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me translate the method parameter there that is an Expression? Like explain it as how it differs from a standard instance parameter?

Comment: Are you familiar with `db.SomeTable.Where(r => r.Value == 42)`?

Answer (score 1):

These are called `Expression Trees` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/).

Basically it's a `lamdba` that can be translated to another platform, from the looks of it some kind of database in your case. This `function` would be translated (by a library) to `SQL` and then executed in the database.

Within the code of your program you would generally only need `lambdas` (`Func<>`), but in some cases you need an `Expression Tree`. Besides your example, sometimes you need a dynamically constructed function which can be done using these.

General information on `lambdas` can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions